# Exclude words with forward slash in Java regexp

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to allow only certain words through a regexp filter in Java, i.e.:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s\\.-_]{1," + s.length() + "}$");
```

But I find that it allows through 140km/h because forward slash isn't handled. Ideally, this word should not be allowed.

Can anyone suggest a fix to my current version?

I'm new to regexp and don't particularly follow it fully yet.

The regexp is in a utils class method as follows:

```
public static boolean checkStringAlphaNumericChars(String s) {
   s = s.trim();
   if ((s == null) || (s.equals(""))) {
        return false;
   }

   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s\\.-_]{1," + s.length() + "}$");
   // Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\s]{1," + s.length() + "}");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
   if (m.matches()) {
       return true;
   }
   else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

I want to allow strings with underscore, space, period, minus. And to ensure that strings with alpha numerics like 123.45 or -500.00 are accepted but where 5,000.00 is not.

Comment: There's really no need for this: `{1," + s.length() + "}`

Comment: So what might replace it to guarantee the each character of a string is correctly parsed?

Comment: What are you escaping the dot? What aren’t you using `\w`?  What are you specifying `{1,`? Why are you using the range of **all code points from dot through underscore** to specify those *49* code points? Why are you using the number of code *units* to specify code *points*? What do you do when those numbers mismatch?  &c&c&c&c&c&die! What are you trying to do in plain English, since we’ll never figure it out from your pattrern?

Comment: NullUserException is right, and you can replace it with the Kleene operator '+'. Since your lower bound is currently 1, I'm assuming you don't want to allow zero-length strings (which you could do by using '*' instead).

Comment: Also, you don't need the '^' and '$' when you use the `match()` method. It tests whether the input is completely matched by the regex. Using the line markers is useful when scanning progressively through a string with `find()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use

```
public static boolean checkStringAlphaNumericChars(String s) { 
    return (s != null) && s.matches("[\\w\\s.-]+"); 
}
```

- The short-circuited null check ensures `s` is not `null` when you try to do `.matches()` on it.
- Using `\w` to look for alphanumerics plus the underscore. tchrist will also be the first to point out this is more correct than `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
- The `+` at the very end ensures you have at least one character (ie: the string is not empty)
- There's no need to use `^` and `$` since `.matches()` tries to match the pattern against the whole string .
- There's also no need to escape the dot (`.`) in a character class.

New Demo: http://ideone.com/qraob

Comment: This is good. But could it be extended to include double barrelled names like fitzwilliam-smythe or 5,000.00 as 5000.00?

Comment: @Mr This already matches `fitzwilliam-smythe`, and you can just include the comma in the character class (eg: `[\\w\\s.,-]+`) if you want to allow commas.

Comment: To check whether a comma is being used as a thousands separator and only then accept it will add unnecessary complexity to the regex IMO, but it can be done.

Comment: Thanks NullUserException. I hate regexp though!

Answer (score 4):

Is it because the hyphen is second-to-last in your character set and is therefore defining a range from the `'.'` to the `'_'`, which includes `'/'`?

Try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s\\._-]$");
```

Also, NullUserException is right in that there is no need for `{1," + s.length() + "}`. The fact you start your expression with `'^'` and end it with `'$'` will ensure that the entire string is consumed.

Finally, you can make use of `\w` as a substitute for `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`, simplifying your expression to `"^[\\w\\s\\.-]$"`

Comment: I find it odd that if I remove the {1," + s.length() + "}, previously valid strings are now rejecting.

Comment: If you find a `[^\w\s.-]`, it invalidates the string.

Comment: @Mr Morgan - Don't simply remove it, replace it with `+`.